# Google Places API Not returning a response

Tags: ios, google-places-api

I am following a [Tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/13160/using-the-google-places-api-with-mapkit) online and I have 2 methods that submit a query to Google Places API. I am trying to get a response back unfortunately, it is not working. I have a few debug numbers in the code. However, here is the code.

```
-(void) queryGooglePlaces{
    NSString *url = @"https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/search/json?location=-33.8670522,151.1957362&radius=500&types=food&name=harbour&sensor=false&key=myKey";

    //Formulate the string as a URL object.
    NSURL *googleRequestURL=[NSURL URLWithString:url];
    NSLog(@"1.5");
    // Retrieve the results of the URL.
    dispatch_async(kBgQueue, ^{
        NSData* data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL: googleRequestURL];
        [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(fetchedData:) withObject:data waitUntilDone:YES];
    });
    NSLog(@"2");
}

-(void)fetchedData:(NSData *)responseData {
    //parse out the json data
    NSError* error;
    NSDictionary* json = [NSJSONSerialization 
                          JSONObjectWithData:responseData 

                          options:kNilOptions 
                          error:&error];

    //The results from Google will be an array obtained from the NSDictionary object with the key "results".
    NSArray* places = [json objectForKey:@"results"]; 

    //Write out the data to the console.
    NSLog(@"Google Data: %@", places);
    NSLog(@"3");
}
```

On the log the output goes as such:

```
2012-08-03 16:40:12.411 sCode[25090:1a303] 1.5
2012-08-03 16:40:12.411 sCode[25090:1a303] 2
2012-08-03 16:40:12.512 sCode[25090:1a303] 4
2012-08-03 16:40:12.751 sCode[25090:1a303] Google Data: (
)
2012-08-03 16:40:12.751 sCode[25090:1a303] 3
2012-08-03 16:40:13.628 sCode[25090:1a303] 1
2012-08-03 16:40:14.129 sCode[25090:1a303] 4
```

Can anybody tell me whats going wrong so I didn not get a response.?
yes I did call `[self queryGooglePlaces];` in my `ViewDidLoad` method
Appreciate the help guys! Sorry if im too verbose..just a starter trying to learn!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given the provided code, my best guess is that you need to encode your URL string by adding percent escapes. Try creating `url` like this...

```
NSString *url = @"https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/search/json?location=-33.8670522,151.1957362&radius=500&types=food&name=harbour&sensor=false&key=myKey";
url = [url stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

You would typically make that into one line, but have shown it as two lines for clarity. This will convert those `=` and `&` into properly escaped characters to provide a valid URL.

Comment: well my url is different
however, this particular url, i pulled directly off the Google Places API site and simply replaced my API key. 

So you think the problem lies only in the url?

Comment: The exact URL is irrelevant to your problem. I'm speaking specifically about how that URL is encoded before sending it to the server for processing.

Comment: even when i added that line of code
i didnt get a response :(

Comment: Is `myKey` a variable in your code or did you just put that in there when you posted the code here on Stack Overflow? If that's in the code, you're actually sending the text 'myKey' and not the value of that variable. You should see this if you log the `NSURL` object. If you want to supply that, you need to look at the `stringWithFormat:` method on `NSString`.

Comment: oh i just put that there when i posted to SO

in my actual code, my API key is there

Comment: i simply changed my url string your right that was the problem
thanks!